# Rewrite sql statement in ruby active records

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

let's say I have

```
class KdpReport < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

How do I translate this sql statement  in ruby using active records models?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        `kdp_reports`.`date` AS `date`,
        `kdp_reports`.`book_title` AS `book_title`,
        `kdp_reports`.`marketplace` AS `marketplace`
 FROM
    `kdp_reports`
```

I use ruby "2.4.0"
and active records gem without rails

I can only think of something like this:

```
KdpReport.select(:date).distinct.select(:book_title).distinct.select(:marketplace).distinct
```

Comment: Your proposed solution does exactly what you're asking for. What is the issue? Please stop shitposting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
KdpReport.select('date, book_title, marketplace').distinct
```

For reference, see:

- [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)
- [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#distinct`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct)

You can also pass the values in as an array of symbols, or use `uniq` as an alias for `distinct`, i.e.

```
KdpReport.select([:date, :book_title, :marketplace]).uniq
```